# Solr loses connection with zookeeper and does not reconnect

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

We are having a Solr cloud setup (solr version 4.10.4). It works well except that sometimes, Solr instances loose connection with zookeeper. The exception in the Solr logs say 'No route to Host'. Restarting both the Solr instances solves the issue.
Could that be an issue with the Zookeeper DNS? Even if so, how can restarting Solr fix the issue?. Please help

Exception is as follows

```
"1480390035494","11/29/2016 14:27:15.494 +1100","2016-11-29 14:27:15,494 ERROR ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-18062-exec-18 org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore - org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot talk to ZooKeeper - Updates are disabled.
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.zkCheck(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1555)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:650)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)

Session 0x357b694d40e000e for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)","ip-","608","linux--solr","app/solr","ip-172","/opt/solr.log"
```

Comment: consider using zookeeper ensemble(zookeeper cluster).

Comment: I believe there's a timeout buried in configs somewhere that may be helpful for you.  I forget when solr.in.sh was introduced, but assuming it's in your version of Solr, that's where I'd start.  You're looking for a timeout limit on connecting to Zookeeper.  Probably right next to the ZK_HOST setting?  Perhaps your network has some issue that's making the connection take longer from time to time.  Worth a shot anyway...